# Cannot set CookieContainer due to the state of the HttpWebRequest object error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, silverlight-4.0

I am currently trying to login and get cookies to a remote server using windows phone 7 silverlight in visual studio. I managed to login and get a successful result for login, but when I try to put in the codes to get cookies, it just failed.

It produced error "Cannot set CookieContainer due to the state of the HttpWebRequest object." on my code "request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();"

Can anyone helps me? I can't seem to find the error and I try to look at the documentation and examples but with no luck. Below is my full codes on windows phone 7.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace Testing_Login_
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create();
            string POST_ADDRESS = "http://mywebsite.com";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(POST_ADDRESS, UriKind.Absolute));  
            request.Method = "POST";  
            // don't miss out this  
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(RequestReady), request);  


        }
        // Sumbit the Post Data  
        void RequestReady(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);

            // Hack for solving multi-threading problem  
            // I think this is a bug  
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                // Send the post variables  
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write("username=" + textBoxUsername.Text + "&password=" + passwordBoxSTAMP.Password);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseReady), request);
            });
        }

        // Get the Result  
        void ResponseReady(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                // get the result text  
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();


                if (result == "TRUE")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");

                    //CookieCollection cookieValue = response.Cookies;
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies",  FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
                            {
                                foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine("Cookie: " + cookieValue.ToString());
                                }
                                sw.Close();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    //MessageBox.Show(cookieValue.ToString());

                }
                else if (result == "ICRED")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password incorrect!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error!"+result);
                }
            });
        }
        private void ReadFromIsolatedStorage()
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs =
                   isf.OpenFile("CookieExCookies", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
                    {
                        textBoxCookies.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        sr.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line:-

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

out of `RequestReady` and put it in `buttonLogin_Click` just after you have constructed it.

OR since you aren't re-using it anywhere ditch line altogether.

OR if in fact for things to really work you need to re-use it then construct and hold it somewhere else (such as a field in the class) and assign it to each Request object created **before** you invoke any `BeginGetRequestStream` or `BeginGetResponse`.

Comment: Sorry, currently I am new in coding so may need you to guide me along. I try your first method, it still did not work. I don't really understand by your second and third method? What do you mean by those methods?